# Finding all communication related to any research paper

Tags: publications, peer-review, open-access

Is there any resource (blog or website) where one can find all communication related to any published scientific paper? For example I found some advise on how to write a "rebuttal letters" but not a "real life" rebuttal letter. Same is true for cover letter or reviewers comment. Is there any open-access journal which make everything public (or any researcher have done so)?

Comment: Are you working at some institution? Don't you have access to the respective communication of other researchers within your department, or can you ask them to send you some examples from their earlier publications?

Comment: Try having a look at the various Copernicus/EGU titles - all reviewers notes and responses are public. This won't cover other correspondence with the editor but the reviews & responses are the major element.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It might highly depend on your field of research... But here is a list of tools / resources that can help you track all the documents associated with a paper:

- [Altmetrics](http://www.altmetric.com) track all the online activity associated with a published paper, including Twitter, Facebook or blog posts. [Exemple here](http://www.altmetric.com/details/4561664)
- [Pubpeer](http://pubpeer.com) is a platform for post-reviewing about any published papers
- Exemple of open access journals that include the reviews with the publications: [eLife](http://elifesciences.org) , [Frontiers](http://frontiersin.org/)

I hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet, oddly, might be to guest-edit a journal issue. Canvass your acquaintances for journal editors who might appreciate an apprentice.

You'll also see some of the correspondence just by peer-reviewing, but editing will give you access to the entire process.